# Fetch the values in a data.frame with "winning streak" > 2

Tags: r

I have the following df (my actual df is bigger but this is better to explain)

```
df
    Date   Team Result
1 20-10-2014  Bulls      W
2 20-11-2014  Bulls      W
3 21-11-2014  Bulls      W
4 22-10-2014  Bulls      L
5 23-10-2014  Bulls      L
6 24-10-2014  Bulls      W
7 25-10-2014  Bulls      W
8 26-10-2014  Bulls      L
```

I used `rle` to calculate winning streaks

```
df$Result <- as.character(df$Result)
result.rle <- rle(df$Result)
```

And the maximum amount of streaks

```
sort(w.rle$lengths, decreasing = TRUE)
```

What I would like to do now however is to filter the relevant matches with a winning streak above 2.

I checked out `?rle` and couldn't find what i was looking for. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

My end result should be:

```
#winning streak > 2
        Date   Team Result
1 20-10-2014  Bulls      W
2 20-11-2014  Bulls      W
3 21-11-2014  Bulls      W
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `rle` :

```
df[intersect(which(rep(rle(df$Result)$lengths,rle(df$Result)$lengths)>2),which(rep(rle(df$Result)$values,rle(df$Result)$lengths)=='W')),]
#         Date  Team Result
# 1 20-10-2014 Bulls      W
# 2 20-11-2014 Bulls      W
# 3 21-11-2014 Bulls      W
```

DATA :

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("20-10-2014", "20-11-2014", "21-11-2014", 
"22-10-2014", "23-10-2014", "24-10-2014", "25-10-2014", "26-10-2014"
), Team = c("Bulls", "Bulls", "Bulls", "Bulls", "Bulls", "Bulls", 
"Bulls", "Bulls"), Result = c("W", "W", "W", "L", "L", "W", "W", 
"L")), .Names = c("Date", "Team", "Result"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

`rle(df$Result)` returns a list of two elements : the number of repetitions and the values of the repetitions. We replicate the lengths (we can use `rle(df$Result)$lengths`) to have a vector of the same length as the number of rows of df. We then select the rows with a repetition > 2.

The `intersect` takes the intersection of the index of the rows where :

- there is a >2 streak
- it's a winning streak

In detail :

```
which(rep(rle(df$Result)$values,rle(df$Result)$lengths)=='W')
# [1] 1 2 3 6 7 # Those are the rows where it's a Win. Only those rows can be included

which(rep(rle(df$Result)$lengths,rle(df$Result)$lengths)>2)
# [1] 1 2 3 # those are the rows where it's a streak of 3 wins or losses
```

The intersection will give the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible solution using the `data.table::rleid` function

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
setDT(df)[, indx := .N, by = rleid(Result)][Result == "W" & indx > 2]
#          Date  Team Result indx
# 1: 20-10-2014 Bulls      W    3
# 2: 20-11-2014 Bulls      W    3
# 3: 21-11-2014 Bulls      W    3
```

Another option is to hack the `by` statement so we could reuse the `Result` column in the same call (without creating `indx` separately)

```
df[, .SD[.N > 2 & Result == "W"], by = rleid(df[["Result"]])]
#    rleid       Date  Team Result
# 1:     1 20-10-2014 Bulls      W
# 2:     1 20-11-2014 Bulls      W
# 3:     1 21-11-2014 Bulls      W
```